# Knockout update model with ko.mapping not working with computed fields

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

It seems that if the property 'owner' of a computed field is set to a child element of the view model, the update of the ViewModel with ko.mapping deletes the computed values.

Like in this case, where we have an array of parents (each one with some child elements) and we want a computed field for each parent to display the sum of age of the childs.

When we apply the ViewModel for the first time everything works fine, but if we reapply the mapping after the computed fields has been created, they are deleted.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: parent">

    <div class="cell"><span class="" data-bind="text : $data.comp"></span></div>
</div>
<span data-dind="text: comp"></span>
<script type="text/ecmascript">

    var viewModelJs = { 'parent': [{ 'name': 'pippo', 'childAge': [{ 'age': 15 }, { 'age': 18 }] }, { 'name': 'pluto', 'childAge': [{ 'age': 5 }, { 'age': 13 }] }] };


    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs);

    for (var index in viewModel.parent()) {
        var parent = viewModel.parent()[index];
        parent.comp = ko.computed(
            {
                read: function () {
                    var parent = this;
                    var sum = 0;
                    for (var j in parent.childAge()) {
                        var age = parent.childAge()[j].age();
                        sum += parseInt(age);
                    }
                    return sum;
                },
                owner: parent
            });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    viewModelJs = { 'parent': [{ 'name': 'paperino', 'childAge': [{ 'age': 5 }, { 'age': 18 }] }, { 'name': 'mario', 'childAge': [{ 'age': 5 }, { 'age': 13 }] }] };

    //Everything works fine so far...

    ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs, viewModel);

    //now the computed fields are gone.

</script>
```

Is there a way to preserve those computed fields with the ko.mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property *name* uniquely identifies one item in the array, try to replace your first call to the function **ko.mapping.fromJS** by:

```
var mapping = {
    'parent': {
        key: function(data) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.name);
        }
    }
};
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs, mapping);
```

and use the same *name* values in the second *viewModelJs* definition.

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/abaluz/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it works fine if I have only 1 nested element. But currently this problem still curses me since i must unwrap Observables that are at a deeper level. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just working the same way. See this [sample](http://jsbin.com/ojabaf/4/edit) with 2 levels.

Comment: ok.. but i'll have something like this : http://jsbin.com/ojabaf/7/edit
but didn't work...

Comment: adapted sample: [http://jsbin.com/ojabaf/11/edit](http://jsbin.com/ojabaf/11/edit)